# Efficient way to determine if an element has already appeared in a stream

Tags: python, stream

### The question

Is there any efficient way (with particular attention to memory), either **deterministic** or **probabilistic with arbitrary error**, to determine if *i*-th element has already appeared or not in a stream of strings (such as the one modelled below)?

### Stream model

The stream is modelled by the following generator of strings. In this model, the last `M=10000` values are the ones that appear twice. Obviously in the real application it is not known when a duplicate shall show itself.

```
def binary(n):
    """Return a binary string representing the number."""
    return "{0:b}".format(n)

def stream():
    """Lazily yield the ith element of the stream."""
    N=10000000
    M=10000
    for i in range(N):
        yield binary(i)
    for i in range(M):
        yield binary(i)
```

### Current implementation

My current implementation uses a form of dictionary, using either directly the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or an implementation using [`patricia-trie`](https://github.com/fnl/patricia-trie) customised in such a way to exploit eventual frequent substrings.

```
elements = {}
already_seen = 0
for e in stream():
    if e not in elements:
        elements[e] = None
    else:
        already_seen += 1
```

The `already_seen` value should be `10000`.

The problem with the current implementation is that it requires to maintain in the main memory all the distinct items. Is there any other way?

Comment: aside: you could create a `set` instead of a `dict` for this. Your approach looks all right. I don't see what you need to improve. hashing is very efficent on integers BTW

Comment: Sadly the current way requires to keep in main memory all unique elements, and with big streams it isn't feasible. Probably I should point out it more in the question, thank you for the set suggestion!

Comment: a `set` consumes less memory that a `dict` already :) I don't think it's feasible to know if an element has already been yielded in the stream without memorizing it (if the order is random)

Comment: there's a way without `set`: it's storing the elements in a sorted list. Search is `O(log(n))` vs `O(1)` for `set`, but there's no hash, only the elements stored once. So less memory, just slightly slower lookup

Comment: Sure, there is no way to deterministically do so without memorising all the elements, but the question is about any way, including probabilistic approaches. The issue is quite similar to the [`Flajolet–Martin algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flajolet%E2%80%93Martin_algorithm) one, so I thought there could be a similar known solution.

Comment: aah I see. For instance a simple modulus would find duplicates with the risk of not being a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Bloom Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter):

> Bloom filters are **space-efficient** **probablistic** data structures used to
>   test whether an element is a member of a set.

I used `pybloom-mirror` package to modify your code and set the bloom filter to capacity 20000 and error rate 0.01 (according [BloomFilter calculator](https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=20000&p=0.01&m=&k=) the size of filter is around ~23.4kB). But it can give you false positives.

```
from pybloom import BloomFilter

def binary(n):
    """Return a binary string representing the number."""
    return "{0:b}".format(n)

def stream():
    """Lazily yield the ith element of the stream."""
    N=10000
    M=100
    for i in range(N):
        yield binary(i)
    for i in range(M):
        yield binary(i)

def my_func():
    bf = BloomFilter(capacity=20000, error_rate=0.01)
    already_seen = 0
    for e in stream():
        if e in bf:
            already_seen += 1
        else:
            bf.add(e)
    print(already_seen)

my_func()
```

Output is:

```
100
```

For capacity of 10 million and probability 0.01 the size is around 11.43MiB (there are lot's of variables to play with though, depends on your use case).

Edit:

For chaining Bloom Filters you could use this example:

```
def bloom_filter_chain(n=3):

    # make bloom filters chain, each next chain is with lower error rate.
    bloom_filters = []
    for i in range(n):
        bloom_filters.append(BloomFilter(capacity=20000, error_rate=0.1 ** (i+1)))

    already_seen = 0

    for e in stream():
        we_have_seen = True
        for bf in bloom_filters:
            if e in bf: # might be false positive, continue down the chain
                continue
            else:
                we_have_seen = False
                bf.add(e)
                break
        if we_have_seen:
            already_seen += 1

    print(already_seen)
```

Comment: Is there any way to lower the error even more? Maybe by chaining multiple filters?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti yes, of course (the calculator https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=20000&p=0.001&m=&k= can give you an idea). All depends on quality of  hash function, your input data etc.

Comment: Could you please include in your answer an approach at chaining a given `n` of BloomFilter objects, for future answer-seekers?